Using condition inside subquery
I need to extract only min(id) values. But I don't know how to use condition from upper query into inner query. The error is: invalid identifier. This is part of larger view, with many more tables and columns, for simplicity I've extracted only this part (I can't make CTE or something like that, because this is larger view). If I skip condition inside inner query, then it lasts forever. Is there some solution to this?
The info that I need is if result with min(id) is successfull (status_id = 3). In that case, count(*) = 1. So, result with min(id) was success.
select bj.*
    from SP_BATCH_JOB bj

        left join (
                 select a.BATCH_JOB_ID, count(*) over () done
                     from (select min(c.id) over (partition by c.REQ_ID) min_id,
                                  c.REQ_ID, c.id, c.STATUS_ID, c.BATCH_JOB_ID
                           from pinv_cmd c
                            where c.BATCH_JOB_ID = bj.id --error: invalid identifier
                           ) a
                     where a.id = a.min_id and a.STATUS_ID = 3) ok on ok.BATCH_JOB_ID = bj.id

Sample tables with expected result:
create table NITES_SP.SP_BATCH_JOB
(
    ID                 NUMBER       not null,
    NAME               VARCHAR2(50) not null
);

create table NITES_SP.PINV_CMD
(
    ID                  NUMBER                            not null,
    STATUS_ID           NUMBER                            not null,
    REQ_ID              NUMBER                            not null,
    BATCH_JOB_ID        NUMBER                            not null
);

insert into sp_batch_job (id, name)
select 1, 'First job' from dual
union
select 2, 'Second job' from dual
union
select 3, 'Third job' from dual
/

insert into pinv_cmd (id, status_id, req_id, batch_job_id)
select 1, 3, 55, 1 from dual
union
select 2, 5, 55, 1 from dual
union
select 3, 3, 58, 2 from dual
union
select 4, 3, 58, 2 from dual
union
select 5, 5, 58, 2 from dual
/

Expected result:



BATCH_JOB_ID
DONE




1
1


2
1




Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results (and a minimal example).

You need a LATERAL derived table to reference same FROM list tables.

@jarlh - please provide example

left join LATERAL (....

My version of oracle db is 11.2. Lateral was introduced in 12.1. So I can't use it, unfortunately.

@DaleK - provided samples

Please [edit] your question and explain (in English, not code) what logic you are trying to implement to get that sample output.

The really simple answer is to just remove the line that's erroring, as you're joining on that value later anyway:
select bj.*, ok.done
    from SP_BATCH_JOB bj

        left join (
                 select a.BATCH_JOB_ID, count(*) over () done
                     from (select min(c.id) over (partition by c.REQ_ID) min_id,
                                  c.REQ_ID, c.id, c.STATUS_ID, c.BATCH_JOB_ID
                           from pinv_cmd c
--                            where c.BATCH_JOB_ID = bj.id --error: invalid identifier
                           ) a
                     where a.id = a.min_id and a.STATUS_ID = 3) ok on ok.BATCH_JOB_ID = bj.id




ID
NAME
DONE




1
First job
2


2
Second job
2


3
Third job
null



But that gets 2 not 1, because you've added a window to the count(*) - it looks like that should not be there...
select bj.*, ok.done
    from SP_BATCH_JOB bj

        left join (
                 select a.BATCH_JOB_ID, count(*) done
                     from (select min(c.id) over (partition by c.REQ_ID) min_id,
                                  c.REQ_ID, c.id, c.STATUS_ID, c.BATCH_JOB_ID
                           from pinv_cmd c
                           ) a
                     where a.id = a.min_id and a.STATUS_ID = 3
                  group by a.BATCH_JOB_ID) ok on ok.BATCH_JOB_ID = bj.id




ID
NAME
DONE




1
First job
1


2
Second job
1


3
Third job
null



I've assumed that each req_id is linked to a single batch_job_id (so a batch has multiple requests), but if that isn't the case you can add that to the partition, as @MT0 pointed out:
                 select a.BATCH_JOB_ID, count(*) done
                     from (select min(c.id) over (partition by c.REQ_ID, c.BATCH_JOB_ID) min_id,

With your sample data the result is the same, and it wouldn't hurt to do that anyway even if they are linked.

Another way to get that result, and also show zero for batch 3 (which you may or may not want, as you haven't shown that at all in your example output) is to get the minimum status for each batch/request in a subquery, then count those:
select bj.id, bj.name,
  count(case when tmp.status_id = 3 then tmp.req_id end) as done
from sp_batch_job bj
left join (
  select c.batch_job_id, c.req_id,
    min(c.status_id) keep (dense_rank first order by c.id) as status_id
  from pinv_cmd c
  group by c.batch_job_id, c.req_id
) tmp
on tmp.batch_job_id = bj.id
group by bj.id, bj.name;




ID
NAME
DONE




1
First job
1


2
Second job
1


3
Third job
0



fiddle
(The 11gR2 version of db<>fiddle isn't currently working but I think that syntax is all supported...)
If you don't want to see the row for batch 3, either as null or zero, then use an inner join instead of an outer join.

Your first and second queries aren't the same as the OP's as they use min(c.id) over (partition by c.REQ_ID) in the inner-most sub-query but you've removed the OP's (failed) attempt to use a correlated sub-query on the batch_job_id within that part so now the partition is only on c.REQ_ID and not on batch_job_id as well.

These use min(c.id) over (partition by c.REQ_ID) and then get the matching status_id; I'm doing that in one step with keep. I've assumed req_id is unique to a batch, based on the data and description/attempt, but yes if that's not the case then it can be added to the partition - and wouldn't hurt anyway.

Yes, with the assumed requirement that req_id is unique to a batch_job_id then the queries will work. If that assumption doesn't hold (i.e. fiddle) then min(c.id) over (partition by c.batch_job_id, c.REQ_ID) fixes it.

Indeed. I've noted that in my answer now. Thanks for pointing it out.

This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

You can include BATCH_JOB_ID in the PARTITION BY clause of the analytic function in the inner-most sub-query and then move the filter to the middle sub-query. You have not explained what the logic is that you want to implement but you probably do not want to LEFT OUTER JOIN and either want INNER JOIN or EXISTS:
select id,
       1 AS done
from   SP_BATCH_JOB bj
WHERE  EXISTS(
         select 1
         from   (
           select min(c.id) over (partition by c.BATCH_JOB_ID, c.REQ_ID) min_id,
                  c.REQ_ID,
                  c.id,
                  c.STATUS_ID,
                  c.BATCH_JOB_ID
           from   pinv_cmd c
         ) a
         where a.id = a.min_id
         and   a.STATUS_ID = 3
         and   a.BATCH_JOB_ID = bj.id
       )

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



ID
DONE




1
1


2
1



or:
select bj.id,
       COALESCE(ok.done, 0) AS done
from   SP_BATCH_JOB bj
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         select batch_job_id,
                COUNT(*) AS done
         from   (
           select min(id) over (partition by BATCH_JOB_ID, REQ_ID) min_id,
                  REQ_ID,
                  id,
                  STATUS_ID,
                  BATCH_JOB_ID
           from   pinv_cmd
         )
         where id = min_id
         and   STATUS_ID = 3
         GROUP BY batch_job_id
       ) ok
       ON (ok.BATCH_JOB_ID = bj.id)

Which, if you use UNION ALL (instead of UNION: for your sample data:
create table SP_BATCH_JOB(id, name) AS
select 1, 'First job'  from dual union all
select 2, 'Second job' from dual union all
select 3, 'Third job'  from dual;

create table PINV_CMD (id, status_id, req_id, batch_job_id) AS
select 1, 3, 55, 1 from dual union all
select 2, 5, 55, 1 from dual union all
select 3, 3, 58, 2 from dual union all
select 4, 3, 58, 2 from dual union all
select 3, 3, 58, 2 from dual union all
select 4, 3, 58, 2 from dual;

Outputs:



ID
DONE




2
2


1
1


3
0



fiddle

I need to count how many rows with min(id) was success (status_id = 3).

@FrenkyB Your sample data has no duplicate rows as you use UNION and not UNION ALL so the count will be 1.

@FrenkyB Updated.
